# Import schema using impdp in Oracle error 39083

Tags: oracle

During the import of a schema using datapump when creating the user I get the error:

```
ORA-39083: Fallo de creaci¾n del tipo de objeto USER:"ARI" con el error:
ORA-65096: nombre de usuario o rol com·n no vßlido
```

so none of my objects are created anymore because the main failure, I have momentarily solved it by creating the user that I am going to import before doing the impdp, but if I want it to be done from datapump, I am working with Oracle 18c Do you know what this error is due to? my exported schema is from a database without pdb and I am importing it into a database with pdb, when I import on the same database from where it was exported there if the user is created without any problem.

This is my command to import:

```
impdp barby/ari@sire schemas=ARI directory=TEST_DIR DUMPFILE=20200610ARI.dmp logfile=expdp20200610ARI.log
```

Comment: 65096, 00000, "invalid common user or role name"
 *Cause:  An attempt was made to create a common user or role with a name
          that was not valid for common users or roles. In addition to the
          usual rules for user and role names, common user and role names
          must consist only of ASCII characters, and must contain the prefix
          specified in common_user_prefix parameter.
 *Action: Specify a valid common user or role name.
//

Comment: Do you import in `CDB$ROOT` or a in CDB ? Did you create a common user or a local user ?

Comment: It is a local user, when I import the schema in the same instance if it was created (export the schema, delete it and finally import it) this instance is without a container, but when I import it in a different instance and if it is with a container it throws me error that user cannot be created

Comment: sorry but I did not understand your last comment, could you be more specific please

Comment: If your pdb name is `orclpdb` then your impdp command should be `impdp system/password@orclpdb....` or `impdp system/password@hostname:1521/orclpdb...`.It helps if you post complete commands leading errors.

Comment: Aaa ok I understand then it is the name of the pdb not the sid, I will try and update my status, for the moment thank you very much

Comment: I have made your recommendation but I do not care about any data, I do not get any error but the scheme is not there, my import is done with **impdp barby/ari@127.0.0.1:1521/sirepdb schemas=ARI directory=TEST_DIR DUMPFILE=20200610ARI.dmp logfile=expdp20200610ARI.log**

Comment: I had a permission problem I have solved it assigned the role of imp_full_database, thank you very much